# Ignore property to the IdentityUser in UI

Tags: c#, abp

i'm using abp 4.4.2 with razor and i want to ignore the PhoneNumber,i was do this in my EntityExtensionMapping:

```
OneTimeRunner.Run(() =>
            {
                
                ObjectExtensionManager.Instance.MapEfCoreEntity<IdentityUser>(i => i.Ignore("PhoneNumber"));
            });
```

after the adding Migration i have this generated code

```
public partial class IdentityUpdate : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "PhoneNumber",
                table: "AbpUsers");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "PhoneNumber",
                table: "AbpUsers",
                type: "nvarchar(16)",
                maxLength: 16,
                nullable: true);
        }
    }
```

after the update database, the AbpUsers Table not have the PhoneNumber, However when i want to ignore the field into the user interface in the ModuleExtensionConfigurator,

```
ObjectExtensionManager.Instance.Modules()
                .ConfigureIdentity(identity =>
                {
                    identity.ConfigureUser(user =>
                    {
                        user.AddOrUpdateProperty<string>(
                            "PhoneNumber",
                            property =>
                            {
                                property.UI.OnTable.IsVisible = false;
                                property.UI.OnCreateForm.IsVisible = false;
                                property.UI.OnEditForm.IsVisible = false;
                            });
                    });
                });
```

The /Identity/Users page and Create/Edit pop-up display again the PhoneNumber.

How can i do ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the [/Identity/Users/index.js](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/identity/src/Volo.Abp.Identity.Web/Pages/Identity/Users/index.js#L69-L95) file to ignore the `PhoneNumber` column.

For this create a folder structure like **Identity -> Users -> index.js** under your **Pages** folder. Copy and paste the [original content](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/identity/src/Volo.Abp.Identity.Web/Pages/Identity/Users/index.js) of the **index.js** (that defined in Identity module) file to your **index.js** file and remove the `PhoneNumber` column  related lines from it.

Check the [UI Customization](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Customization-User-Interface) document for more info.

**File Structure:**

[image]

**Your index.js file:**

[image]

Comment: However this does not modify the create & edit formular.